# Can't change css background property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I have an element with 2 backgrounds

I want to add an image beneath the last one so I'm taking the current background and adding a base64 image

It doesn't seem to work though, the style attribute of the element never changes... If I used background-image, the picture would not stay beneath the color though

a snippet:

```js
let src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";
let data = $("#obj").css("background") + `, url("${src}")`;
$("#obj").css("background", data);
```

```css
#obj{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(37, 45, 71, 0), rgba(37, 45, 71, 1) 20%), rgba(255, 45, 71, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="obj">Test object</div>
```

**EDIT**

Weirdest thing:

```
e.style.background = 
    "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(37, 45, 71, 0), #252d47 20%),
    #252d47,
    url("+src+")";
```

doesn't work, but following does:

```
e.style.background =
    "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(37, 45, 71, 0), #252d47 20%),
    url("+src+")"
```

I have no idea...

**EDIT 2**

After realising js was not gonna let me do what i wanted, i just wrapped my element in another one and attached the background to the parent

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `.css()` doesn't work, but if you use `.attr` with style, it seems to work properly:

```js
let src = "data:image/gif;base64,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";
let data = $("#obj").css("background") + `, url("${src}")`;
$("#obj").attr("style", "background: " + data);
```

```css
#obj{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(37, 45, 71, 0), rgba(37, 45, 71, 1) 20%), rgba(255, 45, 71, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="obj">Test object</div>
```

Comment: That is somewhat of a solution, but it won't be easy to manipulate other styles...

Comment: just append them to you string: 
`$("#obj").attr("style", "background: " + data + "; color:red");`

Comment: I'm animating another property while changing the background, so it's all messed up

Comment: why don't you add and remove classes and use transitions to do your animations?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's something so obvious I didn't even think about it. Well I wrapped the element in another one and It's working well so..